# How to create a second Window in OpenGL/GLFW

Tags: opengl, windows, glfw

I would like to have 2 windows. 1 for display purposes and one for settings / buttons (for example to change the color of the background in my main display). How would I go about having a second window for these settings? Would I just create another window?

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "Settings", nullptr, nullptr);
```

Comment: It's been too long since I've dealt with this to make a proper answer, but look into `wglMakeCurrent`. You should find some decent tutorials or examples involving switching windows with it.